# Selenium IDE integrations for screenshot comparison, any freeware tools?

Tags: selenium-ide, screenshot

Any freeware to use to replace costly Applitools for purpose of automatic snapshot taking and comparison in selenium IDE?

Comment: Not a SIDE integration—therefore a comment—but an open-source alternative for visual testing: [recheck-web](https://github.com/retest/recheck-web/). There is also a [Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/recheck-web-demo/ifbcdobnjihilgldbjeomakdaejhplii/) available. Disclaimer: I work for [retest](https://retest.de/).

Comment: You may use Galen framework, it is free with minimal coding.

Comment: @KenilFadia please note that Galen is quite different from what the OP mentions, i.e., Applitools. Most importantly, it doesn't follow the principle [Golden Master Testing](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/tags/characterization-testing/info/), you have to write and maintain specifications manually. And only the stuff covered by those specifications gets tested, everything else is implicitly allowed.